# how to get Drupal user's fans count using friendlist module?

Tags: json, drupal, module

I'm trying to get **count** of fans for each user to be shown in Views , I'm using Drupal 6 with (friendlist module) connected to android program, for that the View Style should be **JSON data document**

I expect the data preview of the view to be:

```
    {
"followingcount" : [
{
  "user" : {
    "picture" : "\n ",
    "name" : "adminadmin",
    "uid" : "65",
    "followerscount":"1500"

  }
```

thanx in advance

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be probably with the [Views Datasource](http://drupal.org/project/views_datasource) module. This will export anything you do in the view to JSON, so that solves your first problem.

**UPDATE:**
To group the items using a GROUP BY in sql, you can use the [views group by module](http://drupal.org/project/views_groupby).

Alternatively, you can write a custom handler to do something simular if you need to perform other operations this module will not be able to do.

Comment: I used this module and its really perfect,,, but my problem with counter,, I played with views alot with no use. thanx for replay @General Redneck

Comment: @MuhammedSwalha Check out [views group by](http://drupal.org/project/views_groupby) and see if it will help you. Not sure on the standarization of this module. It might be helpful to get in #drupal-views on IRC to see if there is a better answer to this. I've often had to really write a custom handler to get the count of a field.

Comment: it seems like what I'm exactly looking for,,, really thanx alot @GeneralRedneck   :)

Comment: You wouldn't mind selecting this post as an answer would you?